# Game drops to 0 FPS and CPU Usage drops to 0%

Tags: cpu, power-supply, fps, framerate

So for about 2 weeks now I've experienced a problem while gaming. My frame rate would drop to 0 and my computer's CPU Usage would drop to 0% at the same time. This would stay this low for up to 30 seconds.

My specs:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Intel Core i5-3570 3.40GHz
- AMD Radeon R9 270X
- 16GB DDR3 RAM
- TM-420-PSAR-I3 Power Supply, which I changed to a GIGABYTE PoweRock AX600

I asked this question on a different forum and they said it was my power supply that was failing and they were surprised it hadn't exploded yet. They had recommended I get a new power supply that was at least 550W. I took their word and upgraded my power supply about 30 minutes ago to a GIGABYTE PoweRock AX600.

After changing power supply, I tried and it only made it worst. My game frame rate still drops to 0 and CPU usage also drops to 0% but now, when this happens, the game goes non-responsive.

I would really like to know what is causing this so I can fix it. If you need any more information just ask.

Comment: Are there any warnings or errors in Windows Event Viewer at the time of the poor performance?

Comment: Most of the `R9 270x` cards I am finding indicate they require a 600W power supply.  I highly suspect its still a power supply issue.

Answer (score -1):

There are certain threads and I/O's that are not captured by task mgr that can make a hung CPU process look idle.

Beware of all services that are running using special tools from SysInternals or Perfmonitor.

Disable Windows Backup , Search and see if the condition stops recurring, then prepare log files of all running background processes, services, settings, events using any utility that does this for analysis purposes.

Test memory from boot and then boot to safe mode for testing non game performance

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried replacing your hard drive? This was happening to me with a failing hard drive - my gaming was s l u g g i s h. 60fps all the time, but drops to 0 for a while. So, I replaced my HDD with an SSD and haven't looked back since.